# How should I set up permission for Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently I set `0777` to all the directories and files.
However, I'm scared of being accessed from others.
Log files and all the controllers, models, views, and the files in config are set to `0777`

In general, how they are supposed to be set?

- Log files directory and its files
- controller files
- model files
- view fies
- the files in config directory

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should definitely not use `0777` for your file permissions. This more easily exposes you to vulnerabilities.

In general, follow this principle:

- For folders, use `0755`, which equates to `rwxr-xr-x`. The execute permission allows folder contents to be viewed.

  find /your/rails/dir -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
- For executed scripts, also use `0755`. This allows anyone to execute the scripts, but not make changes (write) to them.
- For all other files, use `0644` which equates to `rw-r--r--`. This allows everyone to read the file, the owner to write to the file, and no one to execute the file. This prevents, among other things, malicious scripts from being uploaded and executed.

  find /your/rails/dir -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
- Optionally, files containing passwords you could consider more restrictive permissions on, especially `config/database.yml` or any files containing passwords for things like mail services (mandrill, sendgrid, postmark), Amazon S3 buckets, or Redis connections. For these files you might use `0600`.

In a production environment, your rails app should be running as the same user (not root) that owns all of these files. This is accomplished most easily by using [passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/), [unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/), or running a web server such as mongrel or webrick as the local user listening on a port such as `localhost:3000`, and having Apache or Nginx reverse proxy to `localhost:3000`.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. This is what I never thought of. Thanks again:)

Comment: could please tell me these cases? `controllers/examples_controller.rb`, `models/example.rb`, `views/controllers/index.html.erb`, `config/database.yml`, `config/environments/production.rb`, `config/routes.rb`, and the files under `tmp` directory

Comment: Apply `0755` to directories and `0644` to files.

Comment: Is it okay to use `0755' instead of `0644'? Because most of the files are already `0755` and takes too much time to change it to `0644`

Comment: You should not use `0755` for files unless they are executable. You can use `find . -type d | xargs chmod 0755` and `find . -type f | xargs chmod 0644`

Comment: Thanks. I did set up `0644` to `controllers/****_controllers.rb` However now I get error somehow. So I set it up back to `0755` I still cannot get it.  your command find . -type d | xargs chmod 0755 and find . -type f | xargs chmod 0644 will solve everything?

Comment: Thanks:) Could you come to this question and answer? I made new question and added more info! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892289/is-this-correct-to-re-set-up-permissions-for-rails-app