# Is this correct to re-set up permissions for Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I made the new user called "rails"
Then owner and group of all the directories and files are set to "rails"

I do have the appliation in `/var/www/html/app`

So I should do `$ cd /var/www/html/app` and execute this?

```
find . -type d | xargs chmod 0755 and find . -type f | xargs chmod 0644
```

Is it going to set up permission for everything, and it'll be all fine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `/var/www/html/app` is the `app` folder for a rails application located at `/var/www/html`, you should be running

`cd /var/www/html`

`find . -type d | xargs chmod 0755`

`find . -type f | xargs chmod 0644`

You might be literally interpreting 'and' incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks. When I executed 0644, it returns this error chmod: cannot access `copy': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `./sample/app/assets/stylesheets/boostrap.css': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `copy.erb': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `./sample/app/views/communities/_topic.html': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `copy.erb': No such file or directory

Comment: @Benjamin  I also having same type of errors by running sudo find . -type f | xargs chmod 0644   
   chmod: changing permissions of `./public/images/library/library_small.png': Operation not permitted , and by running directory permissions sudo find . -type d | xargs chmod 0755 i got chmod: changing permissions of `./public/stylesheets/library': Operation not permitted