# SQLite3 & Unicorn - How to set database to allow write?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, sqlite, unicorn, digital-ocean

I have a website deployed that I want to allow for users to fill out forms. However, the forms cannot be written because the database is currently read only! How can I change SQLite3 to allow any user to write to the database?

Here's my Unicorn.log:

```
root@The-Origin-of-Foods:/home/unicorn# tail -20 log
tail: error reading ‘log’: Is a directory
root@The-Origin-of-Foods:/home/unicorn# cd log
root@The-Origin-of-Foods:/home/unicorn/log# ls
unicorn.log
root@The-Origin-of-Foods:/home/unicorn/log# tail -20 unicorn.log
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  Food Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Food Load (3.8ms)  SELECT "foods".* FROM "foods"
  Rendered foods/_form.html.erb (10.2ms)
  Rendered foods/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (15.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 44ms (Views: 20.7ms | ActiveRecord: 5.6ms)
Started PATCH "/foods/3" for 135.23.129.198 at 2015-03-25 22:35:07 +0000
Processing by FoodsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"hmexKPwxoAvbU9mhgOr7DJnI7PAx92KgTT1ZhHqOnJiiwx2lj4Roi/eoOR1U7EajIxgyyww4rHZaoAG7E+IT6A==", "food"=>{"name"=>"sfasdf", "sciname"=>"asdfj", "origin"=>"asdf", "description"=>"sadf", "years"=>"sdf", "source"=>"hfvjkhj"}, "commit"=>"Update", "id"=>"3"}
  Food Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE "foods"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
   (0.6ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.9ms)  UPDATE "foods" SET "sciname" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "foods"."id" = ?  [["sciname", "asdfj"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-25 22:35:07.663449"], ["id", 3]]
SQLite3::ReadOnlyException: attempt to write a readonly database: UPDATE "foods" SET "sciname" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "foods"."id" = ?
   (0.3ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 45ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::ReadOnlyException: attempt to write a readonly database: UPDATE "foods" SET "sciname" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "foods"."id" = ?):
  app/controllers/foods_controller.rb:36:in `update'
```

I am using Nginx with Unicorn on a DigitalOcean VPS. Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.1.3

Comment: the user running that Rails app must have the right to write into that file. This is a permission problem. You have the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900565/rails-3-1-sqlite-exception

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the solution was to use chmod to change permissions on the file.
I found my database inside db/production.sqlite3. then i used command line and typed:

```
chmod 777 production.sqlite3
```

chmod allows me to change the permissions and classes of which there are 3 types each: read, write, execute and owner, group, others. 777 is a number code that sets the values of these permissions and classes. you can read more about it here http://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/

Comment: This is not great from a security standpoint (ie. ```777``` gives everyone full access to the file)